# Blackberry - How to copy files to SD card using input/output stream?

Tags: java, blackberry, cordova

I am trying to copy my Blackberry assets folder to the SD card using the Input/Output stream. However I cannot seem to get this to work. I get an error message when running the Blackberry simulator indicating `error: cannot find symbol inConn.close(); & outConn.close();`. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

```
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.microedition.io.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.json.me.JSONArray;

public static PluginResult execute(JSONArray args) {
String[] resourseFileNames = {"file1","file2"."file3"};
final int length = resourseFileNames.length;

for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    String srcFile = "file:///store/home/user/sample/www" + resourseFileNames[i];
    FileConnection srcConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(srcFile, Connector.READ);
    InputStream in = srcConn.openInputStream();
    String dstFile = "file:///SDCard/MyAppName/www" + resourseFileNames[i];
    FileConnection dstConn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(dstFile, Connector.WRITE);
    OutputStream out = dstConn.openOutputStream();
    // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    inConn.close();
    out.close();
    outConn.close();
}
    String value = "OK";
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, value);
}
```

I am using Phonegap If that makes any difference. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the `inConn` with `srcConn` and `outConn` with `dstConn`. It is my typo.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My should compile w/o any problems. If you still experience issues, then your should check your other code  pieces (change `{"file1","file2"."file3"};` to `{"file1","file2","file3"};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are not opening the streams correctly. Instead, you should use a separate `FileConnection` for source and destination files. Then use 
 [FileConnection#openInputStream()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#openInputStream%28%29) to open `InputStream` and [FileConnection#openOutputStream()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#openOutputStream%28%29) to open `OutputStream`.

Code snippet:

```
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    try {
        String srcFile = "file:///store/home/user/sample/www" + resourseFileNames[i];
        FileConnection srcConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(srcFile, Connector.READ);
        InputStream in = srcConn.openInputStream();

        String dstFile = "file:///SDCard/myAppName/www" + resourseFileNames[i];
        FileConnection dstConn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(dstFile, Connector.WRITE);
        OutputStream out = dstConn.openOutputStream();

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        srcConn.close();

        out.close();
        dstConn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: Fixed few typos that caused **"cannot find symbol"** error.

**UPDATE 2**: Surrounded the code with try/catch (catching IOException).

Comment: Hi, The above seems exactly what i am looking for, however for some reason when I am trying to use ant build to load up the simulator, I an getting several error message all of which are indicating 'error: cannot find symbol' - these are al the input stream, connectors etc.

Comment: I am currently importing the following classes:                  import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.file;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;   Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have changed a few classes and now its only inConn.close(); & outConn.close(); symbols that cannot be found.

Comment: @weebo123 If `inConn` and `outConn` are of type `FileConnection` then everything should work flawlessly. Otherwise, I've no idea why it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, yes thats what I though, but for some reason it still cannot find that symbol. I have edited my orginal questions code, with your fix implemented into my class, I have also included the current libraries I am importing. Thanks

Comment: Hi MrVincenzo I implemented your fix, however this caused 10 new issues, 'error:unreported exception IOEception; must be caught or declared to be thrown'. Do you think this is to do with my file path string array i get before the beginning on the for loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I did get this working in the end, although i took a slightly different approach. Bare in mind your code helped guide me in that direcetion, again thanks for your help.